# "Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an try point - In solution with multiple projects

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I been trying to split my current asp.net project across multiple projects following the layered architecture but after making some changes i'm not getting an error "Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point in my domain layer project.

My program.cs with the main method is in my presentation layer project:

```
namespace AspNetCore.VueJs
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            BuildWebHost(args).Run();
        }

        public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .Build();
    }
}
```

My csproj for domain layer project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>{85460453-E49C-4FE9-88E5-371A0880966C}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <RootNamespace>Domain</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>Domain</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.6.1</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
    <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
    <Deterministic>true</Deterministic>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="App.config" />
    <None Include="packages.config" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Entities\ExampleEntity.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Identity\ApplicationRole.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Identity\ApplicationRoles.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Identity\ApplicationUser.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Identity\ApplicationUserLogin.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Abstractions, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Abstractions.2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Abstractions.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Core, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Core.2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Core.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.Internal, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.Internal.2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.Internal.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.KeyDerivation, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.KeyDerivation.2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.KeyDerivation.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Abstractions, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Abstractions.2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Abstractions.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions.2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Server.Abstractions, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Server.Abstractions.2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Server.Abstractions.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions.2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions.2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features.2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions.2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder.2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Abstractions, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Abstractions.2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Abstractions.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions.2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Core, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Core.2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Core.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Stores, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Stores.2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Stores.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions.2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.ObjectPool, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.ObjectPool.2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.ObjectPool.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Options, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.Options.2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Options.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.WebEncoders, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.WebEncoders.2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.WebEncoders.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers.2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Win32.Registry, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Win32.Registry.4.5.0\lib\net461\Microsoft.Win32.Registry.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Buffers, Version=4.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Buffers.4.5.0\lib\netstandard2.0\System.Buffers.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.ComponentModel.Annotations, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.ComponentModel.Annotations.4.5.0\lib\net461\System.ComponentModel.Annotations.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data.OracleClient" />
    <Reference Include="System.Drawing" />
    <Reference Include="System.Memory, Version=4.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Memory.4.5.1\lib\netstandard2.0\System.Memory.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Net" />
    <Reference Include="System.Numerics" />
    <Reference Include="System.Numerics.Vectors, Version=4.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Numerics.Vectors.4.4.0\lib\net46\System.Numerics.Vectors.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe, Version=4.0.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.4.5.1\lib\netstandard2.0\System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Security" />
    <Reference Include="System.Security.AccessControl, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Security.AccessControl.4.5.0\lib\net461\System.Security.AccessControl.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Security.Cryptography.Xml, Version=4.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.4.5.0\lib\net461\System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Security.Permissions, Version=4.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Security.Permissions.4.5.0\lib\net461\System.Security.Permissions.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Security.Principal.Windows, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Security.Principal.Windows.4.5.0\lib\net461\System.Security.Principal.Windows.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.ServiceProcess" />
    <Reference Include="System.Text.Encodings.Web, Version=4.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Text.Encodings.Web.4.5.0\lib\netstandard2.0\System.Text.Encodings.Web.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Transactions" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
</Project>
```

My startup project is set to my Api Project (The one with the main method).

Comment: And which project is marked (bold) as the Startup project in VS?

Comment: @HenkHolterman The api project - the correct one

Comment: Ah I fixed it, the project was set to output type console application instead of class library